# Can I Save a content search web part as a template?

Tags: web-part, content-query-web-part

On our SharePoint Online instance I have created a new site collection and, on its home page I have added a content search web part that is configured to list all the sub-sites for the site collection.

I would like to use this approach for all of our site collections.

Is there some way I can save either the site or the content search configuration so that I can use it as a template?

Essentially I want a component called something like "Site List" which I can add to the first page of every site collection without having to configure the content search every time.

Is this possible and if so can anyone advise how it might be done?

Thanks in advance